# Stripe Checkout subscription mode does not return a PaymentIntent

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I'm using the PHP client SDK, but I'm guessing this is the behavior in general.

After creating a Stripe Checkout Session in 'subscription' mode, the session that gets returned is missing the payment_intent field.

The 'subscription' field in the created Checkout Session object is also null.

Is this intentional? Am I doing something wrong?

Here is the object I pass on to Stripe SDK for Checkout Session creation:

```
 $session_data = array(
            'success_url' => $success_url,
            'cancel_url' => $cancel_url,
            'payment_method_types' => ['card'],
            'customer' => $customer->id,
            'line_items' => $line_items,
            'mode' => 'subscription'
        );
```

Comment: [Hope this will help](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64859356/4248328) . Please provide `payment_method`